# Дублирование Toolbar'ов

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

Откуда вообще берется второй тулбар если в коде я прописую только один?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Activity.java

```
public class LearnActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_learn);
}
}
```

layout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
style="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: AppBarLayout если убрать?

Comment: @Андроид Андроид тогда один тулбар исчезнет, но верхний все равно останется. и мне не понятно где он вобще прописан, откуда он берется?

Comment: Это не тулбар, а системный экшенбар. Используйте для приложения тему с NoActionBar, чтобы убрать его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы хотите использовать свой туллбар, то должны использовать тему без тулбара. В противном случае он и темой добавляется и у вас в разметке есть второй. Так же не забудьте сделать свой тулбар основным вызвав в активити

```
setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
```